# Related conditions to going-up property

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

A ring homomorphism $f:A\to B$ has the going-up property if the thesis of the going-up theorem holds for $f(A)\subseteq B$. For the three conditions below, prove that 1$\implies$2$\iff$3.

1. $f^*:=\operatorname{Spec}f$ is a closed map;
2. $f$ has the going-up property;
3. if $q\subset B$ is a prime ideal and $p$ its contraction, the induced map $\operatorname{Spec}A/p\to\operatorname{Spec}B/q$ is surjective.

Let $p\subset A$ be a prime ideal, $q\subset B$ a prime ideal whose contraction is $p$. When $f$ hasn't (necessarily) the going-up property, $f^*(V(q_1))\subseteq V(p_1)$ still holds; so the condition 3 and 2 are both equivalent to $f^*(V(q_1))=V(p_1)$. Plus, when $f$ is closed, for any ideal $I\subseteq B$, $f^*(V(I))=V(f^{-1}(I))$; just set $I=p$. In fact, I would say that 1 and 2 are not equivalent because (assuming 2) we are not granted that the image of $V(I)$ is closed, unless $I$ is prime. Does the proof work?